# Running an exe file from another exe file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, exe

I need to create a setup where there are two exe files in it and one exe must run after the other exe file. Is there way to do this without including a bat file? (Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to create my setup)

Comment: What are these other executables? You might want to install those using the bootstrapper/pre-requisite mechanism available for Visual Studio Setup and Deployment projects.

Answer (score 3):

Use CreateProcess() (watch out for the privileges!) or ShellExecuteEx()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `system()` function to execute other program. Its prototype is in `stdlib.h`. This is simple method that will work on others than Windows systems too, but if you want more control you can use Windows API as in Bartosz response.